# Understanding this sentence: あなたのこれと僕のこれをぱくってください。

Tags: word-choice

あなたのこれと僕のこれをぱくってください。

This was included as an example sentence in this my [北海道弁辞典]{ほっかいどうべんじてん}. To help clear up any confusion, the term in question, ぱくる, is equivalent to [交換]{こうかん}する, according to the dictionary's 意味{いみ} section. Now, I understand the words, but I'm not sure why これ is used like this. It'd be something like, "Please exchange my this with your this." I'm confused on why it's phrased like this and why a different phrasing wasn't used.

Update: l'électeur pointed out that this expression would make more sense if there was more than one object on each side. For example, if I had three types of candy and you had three crackers, and I proposed lets exchange one of your crackers or one of my candies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This meaning is confusing because in English we really don't modify words like "this" in the same way. However, if you think of "僕のこれ" as a combination of "this" and "mine", it makes more sense. For example, imagine that the person is pointing to two objects so it is clear what "これ” means.

I'd translate this as "Let's trade this, of yours, with this, of mine".

This sort of usage can be seen with other こそあど words like それ.

Make sense?

Comment: 合計で２点のアイテムが目の前にある状態を想像されているという意味でしょうか。そうだとすると、不可能ではないにせよ、やや苦しい説明になっているかと思います。私は最低でも計4点(2点x2名)、もしくはより多くのアイテム数から２点(1点ｘ2名)を選択して、交換したいと言っている様子を頭に描いています。

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thank you, Locksleyu. I kinda had a feeling it was something like what you said, but I'm never sure.

Comment: l'électeur: そうですね。合計で２点のアイテムだけだとそういう言い方は使いませんね。

Comment: By the way, ばくる(bakuru) is right, ぱくる(pakuru, usually written
 パクる) is another verb. I'm from Hokkaido.